# Snaplogic - Expression Language Syntax - unique array value

Tags: expression, jsonpath, snaplogic

I am using following EL

```
jsonPath($, "$array.map({id: value.get('id'), type: value.get('type') })")
```

which produces the next variable ...

But the key(id) is not kept unique ?!

```
        [{
            "id": "1",
            "type": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "2"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "1"
        }]
```

What can i use in snaplogic expression language or a snap to get the following unique key array :

```
           [{
                "id": "1",
                "types": ["1", "2"],
            {
                "id": "2",
                "type": ["1"]
            }]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group By Fields` snap to group based on `id` and then use a simple mapper to create the desired JSON. Please note that you have to sort the incoming documents by `id` before doing the group by.

**Sample Pipeline**

[image]

**Final Mapper expressions**

`$groupBy.id` mapped to **id**

`jsonPath($, "$groups[*].type")` mapped to **types**

**Resulting output**

[image]